# Where can I find a copy of the Project Euler questions?

Tags: reference-request, online-resources, project-euler

The Project Euler page is currently offline, and I would very much like to do the problems still. Does anyone know where I can find a transcript of the problems?

Comment: I don't know where to find it right now, but from projecteuler's website is possible to download a pdf containing all the problems, maybe it ll be useful the next time it is offline

Comment: I'm sure that if you wait a few days, they'll be back up and running.

Comment: https://archive.org/web/

Comment: @mixedmath They specified on their website that it is unclear by when the site will be running again.

Comment: I downloaded all the html a while ago but I don't seem to have downloaded the images... so some of the formulas don't show.

Comment: At this moment https://projecteuler.net seems to be back online.

Comment: https://github.com/jxu/project-euler-offline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the cached version. Say you want problem number X.

1. Go to google.
2. Search 'project euler problem X'.
3. Among the search results you will find "projecteuler.net/problem=X".
4. Click on the green triangle in front of that link.
5. Click on "cached" from the drop down menu.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a downloadable archive called [Local Euler](http://kmkeen.com/local-euler/2008-07-16-07-33-00.html) that a kind person made.

> I threw together a little script to compile every problem together in a single flat text file, adding the attachments in a zip file. ... The conversion process goes to some lengths to ensure a highly readable copy.

It appears to be current to at least mid-2014 as of this writing.